# Remotely install Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, servicecontroller

How do I remotely install a Windows service using C#?
(I prefer not calling sc.exe / psexec / powershell remoting).

Thanks!
Yuval

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at the [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) project. They make deployment of windows services pretty painless. XCopy and invoke with any of [these command line options](http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/command-line-syntax/) and you should be good to go.